# Initialize a jQuery plugin when the content for an Ember.View has loaded

Tags: jquery, view, ember.js, ember-data

```
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6 ember.js
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 ember.js
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
```

The controller is an `Ember.ArrayContoller` & the content is loaded via the `DS.RESTAdapter`.

This is the code I think I want, but it is never executed. I want to add an observer to `controller.content` for the `isLoaded` event.

```
App.ThumbnailScrollerView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  didInsertElement: function() {
    return this.get("controller.content").addObserver("isLoaded", function() {
      return $(".jThumbnailScroller").thumbnailScroller();
    });
  }
});
```

This code is executed, but once for each object, I really only want it for the last object. `controller.content.@each`

```
App.ThumbnailScrollerView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  didInsertElement: function() {
    return this.get("controller.content.@each").addObserver("isLoaded", function() {
      return $(".jThumbnailScroller").thumbnailScroller();
    });
  }
});
```

This is also never executed. `controller.content.lastObject`

```
App.ThumbnailScrollerView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  didInsertElement: function() {
    return this.get("controller.content.lastObject").addObserver("isLoaded", function() {
      return $(".jThumbnailScroller").thumbnailScroller();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a quick guess, Do you call `.thumbnailScroller()` after returning it? Otherwise I guess you should return `$(".jThumbnailScroller").thumbnailScroller()`

Comment: @intuitivepixel Oops, thanks! That was a typo here, but not the actual problem. I fixed it above.

Comment: Have you tried doing it like so `"controller.content.[]"`?

Comment: @intuitivepixel That is not executed either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `controller.content` is a ManyArray and ManyArrays do not implement isLoaded. They do have an isUpdating property.

Template:

```
{{#if content.isUpdating}}
  LOADING...
{{else}}
  {{view App.ThumbnailScrollerView}}
{{/if}}
```

App.ThumbnailScrollerView:

```
 setupThumbnailScroller: function() {
   this.$('.jThumbnailScroller').thumbnailScroller();
 }.on('didInsertElement')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `RESTAdapter` by the time Ember gets to the view/template it's already too late to observe `isLoaded`. This is by design and a key idea behind the Async router in RC.6.

Using the `RESTAdapter` will result in a promise being return in your `model` hook when you fetch data from the server. The workflow of the router is something like,

1. `model` hook looks up data via `MyModel.find` etc, and returns a promise.
2. The async router pauses when it sees the promise and waits for the fetch to be completed.
3. Then the router calles `setupController` and wires up the data returned to the controller.
4. Finally the `renderTemplate` is called to render the template with this data.

So by the time the view renders, the data has finished loading. The `@each` is for a computed property that iterates over the content, and isn't relevant here.

Now, If my understanding of the question is correct. You have some content that loads via the model hook, and writes out the DOM that the `thumbnail scroller` expects in your corresponding template.

After these images have finished loading you want to call the `thumnailScroller()` on the target div, which would initialize this plugin.

ie:- You want to hook into an event when all images have loaded, and not when the data backing the content is loaded.

Ember doesn't provide any such events for image load. You will need to use an external library like [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) to do this.

`imagesLoaded` provides callbacks for events like `always` and `done` to watch for such image completion events. Your `didInsertElement` method for this would be,

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  var _this = this;
  var loader = imagesLoaded('.jThumbnailScroller');

  loader.on('always', function() {
    _this.$('.loader').hide();
    _this.$('.jThumbnailScroller').thumbnailScroller();
  });

  loader.on('progress', function(loader, image) {
    _this.set('nowLoading', image.img.src);
  });
}
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/isutat/1) example. It uses jQuery promises with the Flickr API, but the same principles apply with ember-data's `RESTAdapter`.