# Reacting to a controller/view initialization event

Tags: ember.js

As you can see in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/etines/3), I am trying to do the following:

1. Load some data. Data is loaded from a `FIXTURE`, slowly, because we have a high `latency` in the `FIXTURE`.
2. While the data is being loaded, I want to show some simple text: `Loading ...`
3. Once the data is received, show an outlet with the real data.

I have tried with `controllers.nodesIndex.isUpdating`, `isLoading`, `isUpdated` `.isLoaded`, and several other variations, but this is not working. How can I react to a "data is ready" event?

### EDIT

I have also tried with a property binding `dataLoaded`; in the route, when the data is received, I manually update the property. But this is also not working. I am getting several error messages:

```
Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.

Assertion failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications

Uncaught Error: You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state
```

This is the template:

```
      <div id="legend" class="">
        <legend class="">Nodes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge">{{controllers.nodesIndex.length}} records</span></legend>
      </div>

      <!-- Just to get visual feedback when the data gets loaded -->
      {{outlet}}

      {{#if controllers.nodesIndex.dataLoaded}}
          <!-- This should only be shown when the data is ready -->
          {{outlet}}
      {{else}}
          Loading ...
      {{/if}}

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</article>
```

This is the controller:

```
App.NodesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    dataLoadedBinding: 'App.nodesLoaded'
});
```

And this is the route:

```
App.NodesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Node.find().then(function(data) {
            console.log('Data received > data=%o', data);
            App.set('nodesLoaded', true);
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: there is no `slowIndex` controller in your jsbin, is this intentionally?

Comment: @intuitivepixel: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected the jsfiddle and also updated my question with another alternative, which is also not working.

Comment: My understanding of the async router was that it pauses for data to finish loading if the hook returns a promise. `setupController` and `renderTemplate` are not called until model resolution. Hence you can't have progress updates on the same template.

Comment: I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851533/initialize-a-jquery-plugin-when-the-content-for-an-ember-view-has-loaded/17856914#17856914) with an explanation on these lines, but the answer with `content.isUpdating` is what work for the poster. It also seems to be the correct way to do this(?) judging by the popularity of that answer. So I am also a little confused on this aspect. @intuitivepixel may have a better answer.

Comment: Thanks @DarshanSawardekar! I have tried `{{#if controllers.nodesIndex.content.isUpdating}}` and it is doing what I expected. Thanks! If you want to put that as answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Sure, added. Still not quite sure how this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to provide alternate markup in handlebars for content that is loading appears to be `isUpdating` property of a controller's `content`.

```
{{#if content.isUpdating}}
   {{!-- content markup here --}}
{{else}}
   {{!-- Loading message here --}}
{{/if}}
```